# What is the most optimal way of running an SQL Query with optional arguments?

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js

I'm currently running the following query to add data to a table in my database:

```
INSERT INTO IDEIAS_INTERACOES (CODIGO, ARQUIVO, REMETENTE, MENSAGEM, UNIT, DATA) 
VALUES (@codigo, @file, @remetente, @mensagem, @unit, @data)
```

This works fine, however the `@file` argument isn't always present, and I want the column to be `'Undefined'` in that case. I can accomplish this easily using ternary operators, but the resultant code is messy and probably unoptimal. What's a more elegant way of accomplishing this?

Ps.: I'm using the [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) module.

Comment: I assume the query doesn't change, so the variable should exist.  So, if it's "not present," what is the value of it?

Comment: When not present it is `undefined`.

Comment: You could always do `NullIf(@File, 'Undefined')`

Comment: What database library are you using? I'd expect you could just pass `null` in the parameter array.

Comment: I've taken the freedom of editing your question to match the accepted answer. In any case, if you were using [sql.PreparedStatement](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#prepared-statement) you could just pass the final value from JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments, when the `@file` is not present, its value is `'undefined'`.  You can use `NULLIF` to look for that value and return a `NULL`:

```
INSERT INTO IDEIAS_INTERACOES (CODIGO, ARQUIVO, REMETENTE, MENSAGEM, UNIT, DATA) 
VALUES (@codigo, NULLIF(@file, 'Undefined'), @remetente, @mensagem, @unit, @data)
```